Kid in compound or village with gadget embedded in wrist which stops him running away
Ten or twenty years ago I recall reading (or at least starting) a novel about a (probably teenage) boy living in a village or compound apparently isolated from the rest of the world.
The inhabitants all have a chip (not sure if they called it that) embedded in their wrists. The boy tries to slip out and see what's outside, but as he does so the device in his wrist starts to inflict increasing pain, until eventually it becomes unbearable and he is forced to return.
Iirc he is not punished in any way, and indeed the matter is not even referred to. It is apparently policy to just  let would be runaways find out for themselves that it's impossible.
Does this ring any bells?
